# Jquery .stop not working how I understand it should

Tags: jquery, css

```
   $("#LeftArrow_Wrapper, #RightArrow_Wrapper").hover(
      function () {
          $("#LeftArrow_Button, #RightArrow_Button").stop(true,true).show();
      }
   );
```

When I mouse over the it I just want it to show the arrow but if I swipe my mouse over it multiple times it queues up the show function and my understanding was that the stop would just cut the animation any help would be appreciated.

I have change my code to be just this

```
 $("#LeftArrow_Button, #RightArrow_Button").hover(function () {
                $(this).stop(true,true).show();
            });
```

and I am still getting the queuing issue

Well I have fixed the problem thank you for the reply's. Stop did work how I thought it did, I am just a dope and was updating the wrong .js file. *FACE PALM*

Comment: are you hiding it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

the `.stop` method stops animation on the selected element,
you are stopping the animation on the wrong elements:

```
$("#LeftArrow_Wrapper, #RightArrow_Wrapper").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true,true).show();
});
```

Comment: $("#LeftArrow_Button, #RightArrow_Button").hover(function () {
                    $(this).stop(true,true).show();
                });

Answer (score 0):

Some things to clarify, based on how best I could understand your situation:

**(1)** `.hover()` is actually two-fold: you normally provide a function callback to execute when you `mouseover` onto the elements you specified **and** another to call when you `mouseout`. When you only provide one, it executes the same for both.

```
$(element).hover(
    function () {
        // to execute on mouseover
    },
    function () {
        // to execute on mouseout
    }
);
```

**(2)** Inside an event handler, the element where the event supposedly happened is referenced by `this`. There is virtually no need to select the elements again most of the time.

```
$('#LeftArrow_Wrapper, #RightArrow_Wrapper').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).show();
});
```

**(3)** `.stop()` stops *animations*. Calling `.show()` on its own **does not** trigger jQuery animation on the element (since it's instantaneous), but calling `.show(duration)`, for example, does, because jQuery performs a fade + size over a duration.

### So, what?

All in all, what's happening in your original code is that, when you mouse over an element, it'll show **both** `#LeftArrow_Wrapper` and `#RightArrow_Wrapper` (because of your original **(2)**), but it'll also do the same thing when you mouse out, since you only provide one callback for `.hover()` (see **(1)**).

It doesn't help that your call to `.stop()` is useless, because there's no animation for it to stop (unless there's something else happening outside this piece of code --- it's most certainly not stopping your call to `.show()`).

Your question isn't the most detailed, so what I *think* you want to do is something like this:

```
 $('#LeftArrow_Wrapper, #RightArrow_Wrapper').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).show();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).hide();
    },
 );
```